# Single person with largest number of fMRI scans

Tags: cognitive-neuroscience, neuroimaging

Is there a known single test person of whom the largest number of fMRI scans (while performing different tasks) have been recorded? Are these publicly available?

*I assume some overarching patterns might be seen. (Comparing fMRI scans of different persons performing different tasks may be distracting.)*

Comment: Maybe the Midnight Scan Club? https://openfmri.org/dataset/ds000224/ I'm sure I heard of one person in particular taking multiple scans of themselves at night over months, but I can't find a reference for it now.

Comment: What is unclear about my question? Please let me know, so I can learn!

Comment: My problem with the question is that, typically, biomedical studies will pool data from multiple subjects as to obtain a population mean effect, rather than publish anecdotal evidence. Further, medical ethics in general restricts making public personal identifiers from subjects. I was considering turning these thoughts into an answer, but rather decided no to and vote to close, as they are just comments indeed but justify my reasons to put this question on hold. Further, the *'...some overarching patterns...'* troubles me. What patterns? Functional imaging studies are highly influenced by...

Comment: ...their specific underlying experimental test paradigms. You cannot possibly shove them together and look for 'overarching patterns'. It just doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Ok, I can agree with everything you say. It is obviously more reflected than my question. So I don't want to resist (closing this question).

Comment: You would have to explain to a layman why it should not make sense to compare fMRI scans of one test person performing different  (but somehow related) tasks.

Comment: @HansStricker That sounds like a good question to ask in case you want to learn more about it. ;p